# Merging node lists in XML2XML XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT, and am having problems merging node lists. Would appreciate your help with the following scenario:

Input:

> ```
> >       <A Id="1">
> >         <B Id="4">
> >           <Attr>
> >             <someAttr1>2</someAttr1>
> >             <someAttr2>1</someAttr2>
> >           </Attr>
> >           <C Id="7">
> >             <Attr>
> >              <someAttr3>2</someAttr3>
> >              <someAttr4>1</someAttr4>
> >              <someAttr5>7</someAttr5>
> >             </Attr>
> >           </C>
> >         </B>
> >         <B Id="9">
> >           <Attr>
> >             <someAttr1>6</someAttr1>
> >             <someAttr2>0</someAttr2>
> >           </Attr>
> >           <C Id="11">
> >             <Attr>
> >              <someAttr3>1</someAttr3>
> >              <someAttr4>3</someAttr4>
> >              <someAttr5>5</someAttr5>
> >             </Attr>
> >           </C>
> >         </B>
> >       </A>
> ```

Output:

> ```
>   <A Id="1">
>     <B Id="4">
>       <Attr>
>         <someAttr1>2</someAttr1>
>         <someAttr2>1</someAttr2>
>         <someAttr3>2</someAttr3>
>         <someAttr4>1</someAttr4>
>         <someAttr5>7</someAttr5>
>       </Attr>
>     </B>
>     <B Id="9">
>       <Attr>
>         <someAttr1>6</someAttr1>
>         <someAttr2>0</someAttr2>
>         <someAttr3>1</someAttr3>
>         <someAttr4>3</someAttr4>
>         <someAttr5>5</someAttr5>
>       </Attr>
>     </B>
>   </A>
> ```

Comment: For future reference, it would help alot if you could explain the rules of the transformation, to avoid people having to play "Spot the Difference". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to combine all **Attr** elements that occur at any level under a **B** element.

First, you would need a template to match **B** elements with **Attr** elements

```
<xsl:template match="B[Attr]">
```

And in the template, you would create an **Attr** element, and copy all descendant elements under the **Attr** elements

```
<Attr>
   <xsl:copy-of select=".//Attr/*" />
</Attr>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="B[Attr]">
      <B>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <Attr>
            <xsl:copy-of select=".//Attr/*" />
         </Attr>
      </B>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<A Id="1">
   <B Id="4">
      <Attr>
         <someAttr1>2</someAttr1>
         <someAttr2>1</someAttr2>
         <someAttr3>2</someAttr3>
         <someAttr4>1</someAttr4>
         <someAttr5>7</someAttr5>
      </Attr>
   </B>
   <B Id="9">
      <Attr>
         <someAttr1>6</someAttr1>
         <someAttr2>0</someAttr2>
         <someAttr3>1</someAttr3>
         <someAttr4>3</someAttr4>
         <someAttr5>5</someAttr5>
      </Attr>
   </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select='descendant::Attr'>
                    <xsl:copy-of select='*|@*' />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```